# Создание скрипта для приложения

Tags: java, android, python

На работе в офисе внедрили приложение https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.flowscape.atlas&hl=en FlowScape для бронирования рабочих столов и переговорных. Возможно ли создать какой то скрипт для автоматического бронирования столов и помещений, который бы каждый день в 00:01 ночи бронировал один и тот же стол :) ? Если да то как это сделать, дайте какие нибудь ссылки на ресурсы и т.д. Буду очень благодарен.

Спасибо.

Comment: Ну у них есть веб аппликейшен насколько я понял еще. А значит их апи можно реверсинженернуть и воспроизвести запросы к серверу по расписанию..

Comment: Ещё можно UI тест написать. Чтобы программа сама нажимала нужные кнопки на подсоединённом девайсе с запущенным приложением. Есть даже вот такой сайт, всё это немного облегчающий: https://testproject.io/